# Impossible to install ubuntu 12.10 both with wubi or regularly

Tags: installation, 12.10, nvidia, freeze, acer

I've tried installing Ubuntu 12.10 both with Wubi and from live CD (USB actually), neither of which was successful.

With Wubi, installing it inside Windows, it gives a black screen after the first reboot.
Sometimes it writes:

"Completing the Ubuntu installation. For more installation boot options, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> now... 10...9...8... 0"

and than it freezes again. I also tried pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> and, choosing any of the options, it still freezes.

I've searched on the internet and people say to use `nomodeset` after pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>, but I never get to the screen where I can press <kbd>F6</kbd>. So I added `nomodeset` by hand after `quiet splash` inside the file `wubildr-disk.cfg` (I also tried to take away the `quiet splash` without any sucessful result).

I also tried with the regular installation as a dual-boot.

I can copy Ubuntu live CD onto USB key with Unetbootin and when I do the boot from the USB key, it freezes after Unetbootin asks whether to install Ubuntu/try Ubuntu/check for errors on the CD/etc.

Here, I've also tried out the `nomodeset` trick in the boot file but it failed.

I think the problem is connected with the Nvidia card but I don't now how to solve it.

I have an Acer Aspire 5750G, Intel Core i3, Nvidia GT520m, Windows 7

PS: My first choice would be to install Ubuntu inside Windows (I already had it this way but it blew up when I did the upgrade to 12.04).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting **graphics mode** to **Integrated** in BIOS. I also had the same problem and was able to install Ubuntu by changing this setting. However, Ubuntu does not boot when I change the setting back to original value (I think it was **Switchable**)