# Ubuntu 13.04 detects only 2 out of 4 cores

Tags: ati, 64-bit, cpu, detect

I have just installed and updated ubuntu desktop 13.04 64-bit (3.8.0-19-generic
). I have AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 945 Processor with 4 cores, but the cpuinfo shows only 2 cores avaible. How can I enable the remaining 2 cores (so the flash won't freez hopefully) ?

Comment: kernel updated to 3.8.0-25 and still same problem :/

Comment: Try running this in a terminal: `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`. It will return the number of cores that linux can detect.

Comment: @MiJyn
As I said... it still shows 2 :(
<code>klemik@klemik:~$ grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo<br/>
2</code>

Comment: odd... okay, that was just to make sure that cpuinfo wasn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem on my Acer Aspire 5750G laptop (Intel Core i5-5410M and NVidia). i saw only 2 cores in System Monitor, and those 2 cores were about 80 Celsius hot (and a lot of other problems)

i learned that my NVidia, and its Optimus technology caused all of my problem.

after i disabled the the graphic card in the bios, and booted with removing acpi=off, all 4 cpus were visible, and the temperatures became acceptable (about 50 c, just like in windows7)

i found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240293/my-laptop-only-boots-with-the-acpi-off-parameter-how-can-i-fix-this)

i hope this helps.