# acpi=off needed when BIOS graphics mode is switchable

Tags: boot, 13.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, acpi

I just flashed my laptops bios to newest version and now I have the option to define how i'd like to set my graphic mode. I have the option to check "integrated" and "switchable". The difference seems to be using only internal gpu or both (the dedicated nvidia optimus).

If setting to integrated, I can boot Ubuntu without `acpi=off`, but when setting to "switchable" I need to set `acpi=off` in grub options.

My question is why or how is the acpi option related with the dedicated gpu?

I'd like to use my laptop also for gaming so I'm depending on "switchable". How's the name of the boot option to fix my gpu issue without completely disabling acpi? Since I have [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI) a bunch of options but I don't understand the differences due lack of knowledge.

Comment: Duplicate of  [My laptop only boots with the acpi=off parameter. How can I fix this?](http://askubuntu.com/q/240293) ?? `acpi=off` could be dangerous... tried bumblebee?

Comment: I have not yet setup bumblebee but was going to do after fixing this first. You mean setting up bumblebee will lead to that i can remove acpi=off back? I'll hurry and test. If so, then this is a duplicate - sorry.

Comment: Installing bumblebee did the trick, but the order matters:
acpi=off needed for installing bumblebee, but no acpi=off needed for using bumblebee - but its not really a duplicate, i'll write as anwser

Comment: Have not enough reputation for posting my own answer...

To fix this issue

 - go ahead and install bumblebee
 - remove acpi=off from grub
 - reboot

The tricky part was, I was not able to get bumblebee running (optirun glxspheres). This is because bumblebee needs to have acpi. But as mentioned above, you need first temporary acpi=off to overall be able to install bumblebee.

Comment: @Dionysius You should be able to post an answer now, could you please write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circumstances summerized are: you need acpi on for bumblebee to work, but you can only install the os with acpi off.

This issue appears to only affect ubuntu 12.04 and around that, because since 14.04 and onwards I haven't had this issue anymore (on the same hardware and also other similar hardware). The correct time modifying kernel parameters was key:

Before Installation

- Set gpu-mode to switchable in BIOS

During OS Installation

- Set acpi=off as custom kernel parameter before starting os installation
- install as usual

After finished OS Installation

- install bumblebee
- remove acpi=off as custom kernel in grub configuration
- reboot

You should now be able to boot with working graphics and working bumblebee.